# Date of last MS Office update?

Tags: ms-office

Can I somehow get the date when my ms-office package was last updated?
I am with MS Office 2010 Professional and Windows 7.

Until now I have tried to google it, but could not find anything reliable.

Edit: In order to prevent the close of the question, I would like to point out, it is programming related, because I program in ms-office and suddenly I found out that VBA is behaving strangely. As a part of my research, I have thought that it could be due to some update, lately installed in ms-office.

Comment: You can always check for updates using the following if you need to get the latest updates, not sure if it helps... http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-check-for-updates-for-microsoft-word-2010/

Comment: Thanks, but my idea was to see when was the previous update carried out.

Comment: Check in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\(your office version)\ and check the date modified of the winword.exe ? I would have to assume, any update would update the .exe.

Comment: @GibralterTop this is a good idea. I would assume the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look into Windows `System Control -> Windows Updates -> Update history` Since I have no english Windows version the path might be slightly different.
There should be something like "* `Update for Microsoft Office 2010`".

In the history you will also find a link to the `installed updates` where the updates are sorted by the software they belong to. It might be easier to find all updates for Office 2010 there.

Comment: My windows is also not in English. So, if anyone is using German this is the link: "Systemsteuerung\Alle Systemsteuerungselemente\Windows Update\Updateverlauf anzeigen"

Answer (score 2):

Check in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\(your office version)\

and check the date modified of the winword.exe file. I would have to assume, any update would update the .exe file.

**EDIT:**

Tested, this is correct and the winword.exe is updated, the date modified reflects the update date.